# Как расположить слайдер в блоке?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Делаю сайт для магазина интернет одежды, сам я по направлению разбираюсь в бэке, фронт у меня очень слабоватый, поэтому и случаются такие ситуации, заранее прошу простить за свою глупость.
У меня есть готовый слайдер, коды которого скачанны из блога, но в контексте моего шаблона он располагается неверно.

Отрывок моего html:

```
{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="catalog">
    {% for product, imgs in catalog %}
    <div class="item">
        <ul class="slider">
        {% for img in imgs %}
            <li>
            <input type="radio" id="" name="slide" checked>
            <label for=""></label>
            <img src="{{ img.url }}" alt="Panel 1">
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti nemo, odio sapiente delectus vel accusamus maxime corrupti necessitatibus, unde laboriosam ab a eius eveniet incidunt corporis consectetur aperiam repellendus adipisci!</div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

Немного комментариев:
Теги for динамически формируют мою страницу с продуктами и его изображениями, мне нужно, чтобы эти изображения представляли слайдер для каждого продукта.
Далее скопированный мной код CSS:

```
.slider {
    background-color: #fff;
    box.-shadow: inset 0 0 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                0 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.75),
                0 -1px 1px 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    height: 18.75em;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -9.875em -13em;
    padding: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 25em;
}

/* Frame */

.slider:before {
    background-color: #22130c;
    bottom: -2.5em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.2),
                inset 0 -2px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
                0 5px 50px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25),
                0 20px 20px -15px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                0 30px 20px -15px hsla(0,0%,0%,.15),
                0 40px 20px -15px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    content: '';
    left: -2.5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.5em;
    top: -2.5em;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Mat */

.slider:after {
    background-color: #fff5e5;
    bottom: -1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.2),
                0 -1px 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
                inset 0 2px 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                inset 0 4px 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                inset 0 6px 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    content: '';
    left: -1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1.5em;
    top: -1.5em;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Slides */

.slider li {
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.03);
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
}
.slider input {
    display: none;
}

/* Navigation */

.slider label {
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
    border: .2em solid transparent;
    bottom: .5em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: .5em;
    left: 24em;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .25s;
    width: .5em;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
.slider label:after {
    border-radius: 100%;
    bottom: -.2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .2em #111,
                inset 0 2px 2px #000,
                0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.25);
    content: '';
    left: -.2em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -.2em;
    top: -.2em;
}
.slider:hover label {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.slider input:checked + label {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(1) label {
    left: .5em;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(2) label {
    left: 2em;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(3) label {
    left: 3.5em;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(4) label {
    left: 5em;
}

/* Images */

.slider img {
    height: 18.75em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .25s;
    width: 25em;
    vertical-align: top;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slider li input:checked ~ img {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Поскольку слайдер находится внутри div с дисплеем flex, я поменял left на margin-left, top на margin-top, убрал некоторые отступы, как-то с горем пополам получилось сцентрировать мой слайдер в блок, но я не вижу аналога для position absolute внутри flex контейнера, изображения не накладываются друг на друга, а выходят в виде строки.
Пожалуйста, посоветуйте мне как грамотно изменить код, чтобы мой слайдер находился внутри моего блока div и при этом работал, как нужно.

​